# Using contourf with a longitude-shifted projection in cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy

Using `cartopy`, I'm trying to plot filled contours in a projection centered on a non-zero longitude:

```
from pylab import *
from cartopy import crs

xi = linspace(-180, 180, 37)
yi = linspace(-90, 90, 19)
XI,YI = meshgrid(xi, yi)
ZI = cos(pi*XI/180)*cos(pi*YI/180)

ax = axes( projection = crs.PlateCarree(central_longitude = 90) )
contourf(
    XI, YI, ZI, 10,
    transform=crs.PlateCarree(),
    )
ax.coastlines()

savefig('mwe.pdf')
```

This yields the following plot, which (at some scales) displays a thin vertical line (passing through the center of the darker area) corresponding to the discontinuity in longitude values (180 degrees E or W). This is presumably because the shapes output by `contourf` are not properly joined across the discontinuity.

Is there a way to correct this? Alternatively, can I arbitrarily edit the underlying coordinates used by `coastlines()` to simulate a longitude-shifted projection?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an artefact in the PDF output rather than anything wrong with the plot. If you display the plot to your screen with `show()` instead of saving to PDF you should not see the line anymore, likewise if you save to PNG format.

The problematic PDF rendering is more likely an issue with your PDF viewer, in fact. I ran your code and produced a PDF that has the same problems as yours when viewed with Preview.app or Chrome on MacOS, but when I open it in Acrobat Reader it looks completely fine.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree with you, but I'd like to prevent this problem, because I do not control which viewer will be used by potential readers. After all, every other longitude renders correctly, so it's technically possible to display the contours "the right way".